# Standard compliance of a C macro

Tags: c++, c

I have this little gem here (idea shamlessly stolen from the C-FAQ):

```
/* A lot of checks omitted to get rid of the architectures with a "weird" endianness */
/*...*/
#define MP_ENDIANESS ( (0x41424344ul == *(uint32_t*)"ABCD") ? MP_BIG_ENDIAN : MP_LITTLE_ENDIAN )
```

Is it compliant (that is not an undefined behaviour) to the new current standard (C-18 at the time this question has been asked) and if yes, which of the older ones support it, too?

Is it also standard compliant C++? (Yes, I know about `std::endian`)

Comment: If you're talking about [question 10.1](http://c-faq.com/misc/endiantest.html) in [this C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com), it recommends two different, significantly different techniques which are (AFAIK) still valid.

Comment: Stuff like this makes me want to quit C++...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has several issues:

- `uint32_t` isn't guaranteed to exist
- `"ABCD"`, an array decaying to a `char*` (C) /`char const*` (C++), is not guaranteed to be suitably aligned for `uint32_t*`. If it isn't, the cast is UB
- if the cast went through, the deref (`*(uint32_t*)"ABCD"`) is a strict aliasing violation (UB)

You might want to simply do something like this instead:

```
#if !__cplusplus
    #define LITTLE_ENDIAN_EH() (*(char*)&(int){1});
#else
    //C++ doesn't have compound literals
    static int const LITTLE_ENDIAN_EH_ = 1;
    #define LITTLE_ENDIAN_EH() (*(char*)&LITTLE_ENDIAN_EH_)
#endif
```

(Works because `char` will exist, can alias anything, and has minimal alignment requirements.)

All the macros, including your attempts, have the disadvantage of being unsuitable for preprocessor conditionals (`#if ...`) or in contexts where an integer constant expression is required (`case` labels, array sizes, bitfield sizes), but when used elsewhere, modern compilers will generally treat the result as a compile time constant as far as optimized assembly output is concerned.

Comment: Why given [C11 Standard - 6.5 Expressions(p7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) (last bullet) do you see a strict aliasing violation for C? The cast involving `"a character type"` is specifically allowed?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The OP is casting a `char*`/`char const*` to `uint32_t*` and then using that for accessing the underlying object. It only works vice versa, i.e., when you have an `uint32_t*`, _then_ you can access it through a character pointer.

Comment: I was a bit torn between you and @NathanOliver You answered both questions and hence gets the mark but nevertheless: thanks to you both!

Comment: But isn't the cast and dereference to `uint32_t` itself and not a pointer? Generally gcc is very good at flagging a strict alias violation and type punned pointers, and there is no complaint with `uint32_t u = *(uint32_t*)"ABCD";` (gcc (GCC) 9.1.0)

Comment: Any concern for `0x01020304` middle-endian platforms that store the bytes `02 01 04 03` or `03 04 01 02`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You have an object of type `char[5]` (C) or `char const[5]` (C++) accessed (in this case read) through an lvalue of type `uint32_t`. That looks like a very literal violation of http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7 to me.

Comment: @Eljay You can access the bytes of an `uint32_t` (or more "portably" `uint_least32_t`) via `unsigned char*` and then compose an endianness identifier out of those bytes.

Comment: @PSkocik except here you don't have an "access" you have a comparison between two literal values. One a literal constant of `unsigned long` the other created from a string-literal containing 4-chars cast to type `uint32_t` before type promotion to `unsigned long` occurs (if on a 64-bit platform). No different than how the source for `strlen` works in the cast of 4-chars to `unsigned` to evaluate whether one of 4-bytes are zero per-iteration. I see your point, and I love the clarity of Sect. 6.5, but just as you could `memcpy (u, "ABCD", 4);` the cast and dereference here looks fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `0x41424344ul` is a constant, not a literal. It's an R-value, no access. `"ABCD"` is equivalent to `(char /*static*/[]){'A','B','C','D','\0'}` if C let you put the `static` there. It's an lvalue -- a value locator and you need to access it before you retrieve its value(s). `*(uint32_t*)`  accesses it by letting it decay and casting the resultant pointer to `uint32_t*` (already potential UB per my 2nd bullet point). Using the `uint32_t*` for access then violates 6.5. Yes, you could absolutely do `memcpy` without UB, because `memcpy` is special, but `*(uint32_t*)char_array` is UB.

Comment: Okay, presuming you are right in the interpretation of Sect. 6.5 in C, then is it a bug for gcc not to issue a warning (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11`) for `uint32_t u = *(uint32_t*)"ABCD";`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It could warn about it, yes. It's not even issuing a warning for `printf ("%d", *(int*)"");` and it proceeds to generate code that prints garbage at `-O0`.  If it was an access-less conversion without UB, there's no way you'd be getting garbage from this `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not defined behavior in C++.  `*(uint32_t*)"ABCD"` treats the memory of `"ABCD"` as if it were an `uint32_t`, but since it isn't really, this is a strict aliasing violation and undefined behavior.